# Shortest path in a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm

I am a bit confused, i have following pattern

```
S...*...
....*.....
**...**.
.G1....*.
........
...G2**..
........
....*.G3D
```

meaning of legends are as follows

```
S = source 
D = Destination 
G = point to be visited before reaching destination
. = paths 
* = blocked path
```

Will this approach give me the shortest path?

```
Distance = Min((S,G1) (S,G2) (S,G3))  
Distance = Distance + Min((G1,G2) (G1,G3))  // Assuming that G1 is shortest  
Distance = Distance + Distance(G3 , D)
```

G points can be randomly distributed  and i am using BFS

G<15 and matrix <= 100x100

Comment: Correct answer of which question?

Comment: if i were you, dynamic programming + heap will be a good way to generate the correct result.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, could you elaborate? Are you referring to a heap data structure?

Comment: @aioobe yes. actually i was talking about A* algorithm. heap serves as a fast data structure that extract the most 'likely' way to go.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, A* gives an approximate result. OP is after optimal solution.

Comment: Not if the task is to find the shortest path from S to D visiting all G along the way.

Comment: the problem can be converted to a TSP which is NP-Complete so an optimal solution is impossible in a non trivial problem instance.

Answer (score 1):

No. That won't work. That is what's called a *greedy* approach, and it will not work because it may force you to do a bad last move.

Consider for instance this case:

```
            S                    

 G3         G1     G2               

            D
```

- `G1` is closest to `S`, so that will be chosen first.
- `G2` is then closest to `G1`, so that will be chosen second
- Left is `G3`

i.e. your approach will chose `G1`, `G2`, `G3` while the optimal solution is to visit `G3`, `G1` then `G2` in a straight line.

In fact, it's trivial to reduce the [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) to this problem. Just set `S` and `D` next to each other. This proves that the problem you're describing is NP-hard, i.e. you can't do better than an exhaustive search.

Comment: and G<17 and matrix can be 100x100

Comment: Is an approximate solution ok, or does it have to be optimal?

Comment: Then unless you can exploit some clever trick of the map I believe you'll have to consider all possible permutations of the Gs.

Comment: @aioobe Note that this basically occurs anyway. The first line `Min((S,G1) (S,G2) (S,G3))` requires that we calculate all three distances first. So rather than choose min after this step, perform steps two and three for each possible `(S,Gi)`.

Comment: @MicahSmith, could you elaborate a bit further? If his algorithm choses to go to G1, then why would the distance between S and G1 be interesting after that?

Comment: If you need optimal solution you have to implement a Dijkstra or an A* ('a' star) algorithm

Comment: Dijkstra will give all distances between all nodes, not the shortest path from S to D through all G. A* is not guaranteed to give optimal results.

Comment: A* will give optimal result under certain condition and dijkstra can have a stop condition when the node 'N' is reached

Comment: I don't see how those conditions are met in this fairly general map.

Comment: if h(x) = 0 for all x   :P

Comment: sorry i'm wrong about optimality. I just saw the 'G[i]' thing in OP question.

Comment: @aioobe To "consider all possible permutations of the Gs" you try paths `{S,G1,...},{S,G2,...},{S,G3,...}`. But the first step of each of these attempts is to calculate `(S,Gi)` which can be stored from the first line of OP's algorithm.

Comment: Right. The `(S,Gi)` distance computations is the trivial part though. It's nothing compared to how many alternatives there are to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You have two graphs. First is the one pictured on your schema:

```
S...*...
....*.....
**...**.
.G1....*.
........
...G2**..
........
....*.G3D
```

And second one is (unoriented one):

```
S-G1
S-G2
S-G3
S-D
...
G2-G3
G2-D
```

Use first graph to find edge weights for second one. Then the task is to find `S-*-*-*-D` shortest path for the second graph!

Comment: Finding the shortest `S-*-*-*-D` requires exploring all possible solutions. With up to 15 Gs there are up to 1307674368000 alternatives.

Comment: @aioobe, No doubt. But those task and initial one are equal, that's for sure.