# Minimum distance between start and end by going through must visit points in a maze

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, path-finding, maze, traveling-salesman

So, suppose i have a maze, which has a start point and an end point, marked with Orange and red respectively and my goal is to find the minimum distance between them. The blocked path is represented by black colour and the open path is represented by white colour . However there are two modification done in this.

1. There are some cells which are must visit, marked in grey colour.
2. Any cell can be visited any number of times(even the start, finish and must visit points)

for ex-
    B=Black, W=white, G=grey, R=Red, O=orange

```
         BBBBBB                 BBBBB
         BBGBBB                 BWGGB
MAZE1 => BOWGRB     MAZE2  =>   BOBBB
         BBGBBB                 BWWRB
         BBBBBB                 BBBBB
```

Here in this case ans will be

```
MAZE1 => M[2][1] => [2][2] => [1][2] => [2][2] => [3][2] => [2][2] => [2][3] => [2][4]  = 7
MAZE2 => M[1][1] => [1][2] => [2][2] => [3][2] => [3][3] => [3][2] => [2][2]            = 6
```

As you can see, the nodes appear multiple times

First i thought of using recursion technique (backtracking) but couldn't come to an algorithm. and

So i thought of using this way.

1. I will keep track of all the coordinates of  must visit points, start and end points
2. Find the distance between each node(like in selection sort we compare each and every term, just like that, we get the minimum distance between each node (using BFS))
3. Then apply some minimum distance algorithm. I thought of TSP but it says nodes must be visited exactly once.Here it can be multiple times. I found chinese postman problem, but don't know if it can be applied here. Floyd warshall algorithm is there but it doesn't include every point

How should i proceed, any idea?

Comment: This question seems to be famous these days, I have seen at least 3 questions about this. May I know where do you get this question from?

Comment: Is it famous? I just made a rip off of the original maze question. But now, when i think about it, it can be pretty useful in robotics. Have those questions been answered before? Can you please share the link :)

Comment: For example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395797/shortest-path-in-2d-arrays/25396058#25396058) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407059/shortest-path-in-a-matrix) should be the same problem with yours

Comment: Ok, so i was on right track, its actually a TSP rip off

Comment: So it atually goes like this start-> permuatation of all must points -> End. And the sum of all these distances must be equal to minimum. So it will be like S->must pointA->must point B -> must point C ... ->Goal right??

Comment: Added my answer, please take a look :)

Comment: And [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25385541/1639625) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25368709/1639625) very similar recently asked questions.

Comment: @tobias_k wow, suddenly it reminds me about my old school project, look suspicious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so maybe I will try to solve this another time. Last time, I didn't notice about the fact that you can visit one point as many times as you can, so that appoarch maybe wrong.

First, assume that the total of Start, End and Gray node is N, and Start is 0, End is N - 1 and Gray node is from 1 to N - 2.

We can see that we can represent the `state` at any one time by `(mask, index)`, with index represent the current node we are in, and mask represent all the nodes we already visited (0 < mask < 2^N).

At first, the state is (1,0) or (00000 ... 1,0), which means only city 0 is visited, our goal is to reach  the state (2^N - 1, N - 1) which means all the nodes are visited, and we end the journey at node N - 1.

So, at this point, we can easily see that, we have convert the orignal problem into a graph of state, and our goal is to find the shortest path from State 0 (1,0) to State end (2^N - 1, N - 1), so, applying Dijkstra shortest path algorithm for this new graph, and we have the answer.

Note: the answer is made based on one assumption that N <= 17

Another note: for robotics, the shortest path may not necessary the best path, as the speed for the robot is different when it turns and when it runs in straight line.

Comment: Djikstras isn't it greedy and may not be best. I didn't understand even the whole mask thing. I guess mask would be represented by an integer and integer is 32 bits. So it should be 2^32 right? Do you have some link which i can refer to or may be if you can solve maze2. There N is just 4. The distance matrix in that case {{0,2,3,3}, {2,0,1,5}, {3,1,0,6}, {3,5,6,0}}. Thanks :)

Comment: @zeroinfinity you should learn bitmask technique first,  for example, if you already visited city 0 and 2, so the mask is 3, or binary is 0101 (only bit 0 and 2 are set), similarly, if all cities are visited, the mask is 15, which is 1111 in binary (all 4 bits are set). Dijkstras is greedy, but in this case, it always return best value. Notice that the graph for Dijkstra is not just city to city, but (mask, city) to (mask, city).

Comment: And what would be the weight between the nodes (mask,city) and (mask, city). The distance between then cities right? And in the above problem, initially, we would be having 4 nodes all initialized with mask 0 except(starting node which is 1). Then we find the minimum distance, go to that state and update its mask value and its min distance(or node value or vertex value, whatever we say it) and we do this, until we reach (2^(N-1), N-1). Is my understanding correct or it should be something else

Comment: @zeroinfinity correct, this is the idea :) glad you understand it! The rest of the job is to implement a correct Dijkstra algo

Comment: @zeroinfinity you can easily store the distance by using a two dimension array `dist[1<<N][N]` (1<<N is a shift bit, equivalent to 2^N), one thing is the last state is ((2^N) - 1, N - 1), not (2^(N-1), N-1)